# Installing Wordpress in /var/www/html

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache

I installed Wordpress in /var/www/html. I did this on a virtual machine locally some days ago. I was able to view Wordpress through the browser just by typing the machines IP into my browser.

Now I did the same on a different server. If I call the IP of the server through my browser I'm just seeing the folder html under "Index of /" and I have to click on html to view Wordpress.

Sorry for my vague description, but could maybe someone help me to configure the second server so it behaves like the first one? 
The first one runs on Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS with Apache 2.4.18 and the second one runs on Debian 8.9 with Apache 2.4.10.

Answer (score 1):

On one machine the `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html` but on the other it is `/var/www`.

You've installed Wordpress in `/var/www/html` in both.

You need to either:

- Install Wordpress in the real `DocumentRoot` (i.e. without `html` on the end) *or*
- Change the `DocumentRoot` option in the Apache configuration files to be `/var/www/html`.